How to defeat the There is no current event loop warning in unit tests?
Friends, please tell us how to overcome the problem with warning.
Or explain why this is happening at all?
/home/master/PycharmProjects/src/kernel/system/interrupt_manager.py:28: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
    self.__loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html

Moreover, with a simple start, there is no such warning, it appears when the test is started.
It seems like IsolatedAsyncioTestCase, when running the test, should call asyncio.run() to asyncio.get_event_loop() could get an active loop. but for some unknown reason, this does not happen. And I'm not like I can't Google what to do with it?

pytest 8.1.1 Python 3.11.0rc1

import asyncio
import logging
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from src.kernel.state.state_system import SystemState
from src.kernel.system.interrupt_manager import InterruptManager


class TestInterruptManager(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    """
    Tests for the InterruptManager class, ensuring it properly handles OS interrupt signals
    for a graceful shutdown.
    File: src/kernel/system/interrupt_manager.py
    """

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # Disable logging for the duration of these tests.
        logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)

    async def asyncSetUp(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.loop.set_debug(False)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

    @patch('src.kernel.system.interrupt_manager.asyncio')
    async def test_handler_sets_exit_event(self, mock_asyncio):
        """
        Test that the interrupt handler sets the exit event upon receiving a signal.
        """
        # Creating an ioc for SystemState
        mock_system_state = MagicMock(SystemState)

        # Creating an ioc for asyncio.The event that will be returned when it is called
        mock_exit_event = MagicMock()
        mock_asyncio.Event.return_value = mock_exit_event

        # Creating a mock for the event loop and configuring it so that mock_exit_event.set is called
        # when using call_soon_threadsafe
        mock_event_loop = MagicMock()
        mock_event_loop.call_soon_threadsafe.side_effect = lambda func, *args, **kwargs: func(*args, **kwargs)
        mock_asyncio.get_event_loop.return_value = mock_event_loop

        # # Initialize the InterruptManager with the locked SystemState
        interrupt_manager = InterruptManager(mock_system_state)

        # Simulate signal processing
        interrupt_manager._InterruptManager__signal_handler()

        # Check that exit event has been installed
        mock_exit_event.set.assert_called_once()

    async def asyncTearDown(self):
        self.loop.close()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(None)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # Re-enable logging after all tests in this class are done
        logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

the code under test itself:
import asyncio
import logging
import signal
import sys

from src.kernel.core_services.check_types_method import check_types_method
from src.kernel.logger.dictionary.dictionary_system import DictionarySystem as Msg
from src.kernel.state.state_system import SystemState

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import win32api
    import win32console


class InterruptManager:
    """
    Manages OS-level interrupt signals for graceful shutdown of a system.

    This class sets up handlers for OS signals (e.g., SIGTERM, SIGINT on Unix/Linux,
    CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_BREAK_EVENT on Windows) to safely transition the system into
    an exit state. It leverages the asyncio event loop for asynchronous operation,
    ensuring that the system can respond to shutdown signals even in the middle of
    ongoing tasks.
    """
    @check_types_method
    def __init__(self, system_state: SystemState):
        self.__system_state = system_state
        self.__loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.__exit_event = asyncio.Event()

        if sys.platform != "win32":
            self.__loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, self.__signal_handler)
            self.__loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, self.__signal_handler)
        else:
            self.__setup_windows_signal_handlers()

    def __signal_handler(self):
        """
        A handler for OS signals that triggers the shutdown sequence.

        This method sets an asyncio event that indicates the system should begin
        its shutdown process. It is intended to be called when the application
        receives a shutdown signal from the OS.
        """
        self.__loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.__exit_event.set)

    async def handler(self):
        """
        Waits for a signal from the OS to shut down, after which it changes the state machine to the exit state.
        """
        # Running a coroutine to monitor the state of the system in the background
        asyncio.create_task(self.__monitor_system_state())
        # Waiting for the exit signal
        await self.__exit_event.wait()
        logging.info(Msg.INF_INTERRUPT_MANAGER_HANDLER_MSG1)
        self.__system_state.exit()

    async def __monitor_system_state(self):
        """
        Periodically checks the system status, and if it matches STATE_EXIT or STATE_ERROR,
        sets the exit event.
        """
        while not self.__exit_event.is_set():
            if self.__system_state.state in (SystemState.STATE_EXIT, SystemState.STATE_ERROR):
                self.__exit_event.set()
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    if sys.platform == "win32":
        def __setup_windows_signal_handlers(self):
            def console_ctrl_handler(ctrl_type):
                if ctrl_type in (win32console.CTRL_C_EVENT, win32console.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT):
                    self.__signal_handler()
                    return True
                return False

            win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(console_ctrl_handler, True)

